# Are paragraphs in a (bullet) list item an antipattern?

Tags: typography, typesetting, formatting, user-experience

Say I'm writing a document (maybe an email) and I'm describing 3 possible solutions to a given problem. Each solution can be described in like 3-10 sentences. I'd like to break down the solution taking 10 sentences into 2 paragraphs. How do I do it? The following doesn't seem to be supported by editors.

---

So the problem is blablabla. We identified 3 solutions

1. *Building a quantum carburator.* First sentence. Another sentence.  Lorem ipsum.ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum
   .

   **NOW I'd like to started a paragraph about the cons of the solution....** ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum.
2. *Revamping the microwave neutrinolizer.* ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum
3. *Solution C.*

---

So it there a way to do it? I cannot break the solution into paragraphs, or the point numbering breaks. Or it there a stylistically better solution?

Comment: Not supported by what editor? This is possible in word, open office, inDesign even stackexchange supports this.

Comment: What is "not supported"?

Comment: @joojaa evem stackexchange? when I write some text in a bullet point and hit enter, it automatically creates a new bullet point, instead of inserting a paragraph within the same point...

Comment: @Novellizator you cna use tabs to indent. Auto-numbering is another factor entirely.

Comment: @Bovellizator obviously if there can be two choices it can not rely on only one input! Obviously since adding a list item is more common thats easier to do. Works the same for bullets and numbers. All the ststem is looking for is things to be on same indentation level so add four spaces in front of paragraph (stackexhange), press the up levle button (Word) etc. Auto numbering even understands this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your current setup probably works.

Not good, not bad, but will get the message across. People are used to reading all kinds of *randomly* formatted docs. What you're calling the "antipattern" is actually bad UX.

Also, calling the solutions A, B and C after already numbered as 1, 2 and 3 is redundant. They are either 1,2,3 or A,B,C. Information priority is all over the place in your example.

Second, from a design perspective, you are turning things upside down just to have the 1-2-3 numbering in place.

Bullets are not meant to include the entire "story" with pictures and videos, but instead bullets should list elements in a section, within a story.

Just because you have 3 solutions to the problem, each of them being a "story", and you clearly need to number the solutions (stories) as 1, 2 and 3, that does not mean all this should be made into bullets.

> I cannot break the solution into paragraphs

Why not ?

Think about HTML: you have headings H1, H2, H3, then you have the P and then, the lower priority element is the UL for bullets. These are made so for a reason, generally referred to as *User Experience*.

In my opinion you should consider doing this. Using these oversized headlines will structure your content better and provide better separation between the 3 solutions.

---

### Solution 1

## Building a quantum carburator.

First sentence. Another sentence. Lorem ipsum.ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum

- bullets go here if needed
- bullets go here if needed
- bullets go here if needed

### Solution 2

## Revamping the microwave neutrinolizer

First sentence. Another sentence. Lorem ipsum.ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum

- bullets go here if needed
- bullets go here if needed
- bullets go here if needed

### Solution 3

## Third one needs a title as well

First sentence. Another sentence. Lorem ipsum.ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum

- bullets go here if needed
- bullets go here if needed
- bullets go here if needed

Comment: I edited the example text a bit. "solution A" was just a placeholder name for the concrete shoort name of the solution. So what other structure are you suggesting? Not using lists items to list out the solution at all but to simply jump into creating "sections" for each solution?

Comment: Or even to use bullets to list out the possible solutions (only the short name) and then delving into the multi-paragraph details in separate sections?